# Using stringdist_join with differing column names

Tags: r, stringdist

I have example data as follows:

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
a <- data.frame(x = c("season", "season", "season", "package", "package"), y = c("1","2", "3", "1","6"))


b <- data.frame(x = c("season", "seson", "seson", "package", "pakkage"), w = c("1","2", "3", "2","6"))

c <- data.frame(z = c("season", "seson", "seson", "package", "pakkage"), w = c("1","2", "3", "2","6"))
```

So the following runs fine:

```
d <- stringdist_left_join(a,b, by = "x", max_dist = 2)
```

But merging with a column with a different name is not allowed (note that the join is now `a` and `c`).

```
e <- stringdist_left_join(a,c, by = c("x", "z"), max_dist = 2)
```

I would like to tell `stringdist_left_join` to use two different column names to join by, like the last line of code it `(e)`, but it does not seems to accept it.

Is there any solution to this (other than copying the column and giving it another name)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `=` for two different column names. You can use the following code:

```
e <- stringdist_left_join(a,c, by = c("x" = "z"), max_dist = 2)
```

Output:

```
         x y       z w
1   season 1  season 1
2   season 1   seson 2
3   season 1   seson 3
4   season 2  season 1
5   season 2   seson 2
6   season 2   seson 3
7   season 3  season 1
8   season 3   seson 2
9   season 3   seson 3
10 package 1 package 2
11 package 1 pakkage 6
12 package 6 package 2
13 package 6 pakkage 6
```

Comment: Thanks Quinten! So I guess then there's no way to feed the function a vector with the different names?

Comment: @Tom, No. You have to specify which column matches another column if they have different column names.